# Java Eclipse - 'Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0' when trying to read from JSON

Tags: java, json, eclipse, oop

I am using Java Eclipse to create an event management system which will write and read JSON files. Here I have code which creates a new JSON file...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        //Declaration of variables
        String title = txtTitle.getText();
        String month = (String) cboMonth.getSelectedItem(); 
        String day = (String) cboDate.getSelectedItem();
        String year = (String) cboYear.getSelectedItem();
        String location = txtLocation.getText();
        String description = txtDescription.getText();
        String URL = txtURL.getText();

        // Combine multiple variables together to make a single variable
        String date = month + "" + day + "" + year;

        // Create a new instance of the class called 'Event'
        Event event = new Event();

        // Assign values to the getter/setter methods of this instance
        event.setName(title);
        event.setDate(date);
        event.setLocation(location);
        event.setDesc(description);
        event.setURL(URL);

        // Add this new instance to the 'eventList' array list 
        MainMenu.eventList.add(event);


        // Create a new instance of the class called 'Event'
        JSONObject JSONEvent = new JSONObject();

        // Add data to the JSON file
        JSONEvent.put("Title", title);
        JSONEvent.put("Date", date);
        JSONEvent.put("Location", location);
        JSONEvent.put("Description", description);
        JSONEvent.put("URL", URL);

        // Create a new JSON file called 'Events.json' that has elements added to it
        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("Events.json", true)) {

            file.write("\n");
            file.write(JSONEvent.toJSONString());
            file.flush();

        // Error Handling
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

This code works perfectly fine by creating a JSON file and populating it with JSONObjects. Here is an image of what a single entry in the JSON file looks like... [Single JSON Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxgTW.png)

I then have a separate class with the following code which attempts to read the JSON file and output its contents to the console...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 JSONObject JSONEvent;

 String line = null;


try {
  FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("Events.json");

  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

  while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
  JSONEvent = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(line);

  String title = (String) JSONEvent.get("Title");
  System.out.println(title);

  String date = (String) JSONEvent.get("Date");
  System.out.println(date);

  String location = (String) JSONEvent.get("Location");
  System.out.println(location);

  String description = (String) JSONEvent.get("Description");
  System.out.println(description);

  String URL = (String) JSONEvent.get("URL");
  System.out.println(URL);

  Event event = new Event();
  event.setName(title);
  event.setDate(date);
  event.setLocation(location);
  event.setDesc(description);
  event.setURL(URL);

  MainMenu.eventList.add(event);

  }


  bufferedReader.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following errors in the console...
[Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDEdJ.png)

Does anyone have any idea what this error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing you write to the file is an empty line:

```
file.write("\n");
```

So, when reading the file, you're trying to parse an empty string to JSON, hence the exception: the parser finds the end of its input before even having a chance to parse anything.

Instead of relying on the internal format of the generated JSON, and to write several distinct JSON objects to the file, it would be simpler, and safer, to write a single array of objects all at once in the file (replacing its previous content), and to read the whole array at once in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue. Was trying to write a JSON data record from a file on a Kafka topic. Was getting `Unexpected token END OF FILE at position` . As a fix, I cleared all the `\n` characters from the file and tried sending it to the kafka topic. It worked.